# See previous ./configure options

Tags: compiler-construction, configure

I have a simple question.

I am trying to replicate the setup a colleague of mine did with a program compiled from source. I've located the directory of the source files, and I would like to see the exact command he used to to do the configure.

I'm guessing he didn't run a simple './configure' given the nature of the program. I would like to be able to tell what options he used i.e. ./configure --option1 --option2, etc.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `./config.status --version`.